# undefined method `split' for []:Array Ruby codewars "Who likes it?" Kata

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, function

I've a problems with input array, attempting a Ruby challenge on CodeWars.

Here is the instruction:
Implement a function likes :: [String] -> String, which must take in input array, containing the names of people who like an item. It must return the display text as shown in the examples:

```
likes [] // must be "no one likes this"
likes ["Peter"] // must be "Peter likes this"
likes ["Jacob", "Alex"] // must be "Jacob and Alex like this"
likes ["Max", "John", "Mark"] // must be "Max, John and Mark like this"
likes ["Alex", "Jacob", "Mark", "Max"] // must be "Alex, Jacob and 2 others like this"
```

My try-code is:

```
def likes(names)
  arr = Array.[](names.split(/\W+/))
  if arr.size == 0
    var = "no one likes this"
    return var
  elsif  arr.size == 1
    return  arr[0]+ " likes this "
  elsif  arr.size == 2
    return  arr[0] + "and #{arr[1]} likes this "
  elsif  arr.size == 3
    return "  #{arr[0]}, #{arr[1]} and #{arr[2]} likes this "
  elsif  arr.size >3
    return  "#{arr[0]}, #{arr[1]} and #{arr.size-1} likes this "
  end
end
```

And that's what compile returns:

```
`likes': undefined method `split' for []:Array (NoMethodError)
from `block in 
'
from `block in describe'
from  `measure'
from  `describe'
from  `
'
```

[click to see image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BdXf.png)

Comment: There is no method called `split` for Array.

Comment: To expand on the comment by @vgoff: You are already passing an array to the method. If `names` was a string made up of a list of names, then you would need to split it into an array using `#split`. But since `names` is an array, you can simply eliminate the line of code containing the `#split` method and replace `arr` with `names` throughout your method.

Comment: End of line comments begin with `#` in Ruby. `//` is not supported.

Comment: Oh thanks so much. Really, arr = names works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of confusion in this code that needs to be resolved before it's going to work. If you want to pull out a chunk of an array you can use [`slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-slice), or the simple array notation `names[0,2]` which extracts the first two.

When curious about what arguments you're receiving it's often as simple as adding a bit of code to find out:

```
p names.class.inspect
```

That will dump out something that tells you what sort of object you received. In this case it's an Array.

It's a common mistake for beginners to think in terms of code that's too literal, like you have here with very narrow cases testing for particular array lengths. Really there's just three conditions: More than three people, nobody, and the default case.

First focus on the phrasing that changes and get that right:

```
def name_list(names)
  if (names.empty?)
    # An empty list means:
    'nobody'
  else
    # Special case for the last element in the list, so pull it off
    *names, last = names

    # If there's more than two names remaining then change the
    # phrasing of the last element to indicate "N others"
    if (names.length > 2)
      last = '%d others' % (names.length - 1)
    end

    # Join these together in the "X, Y, and Z" format.
    (names[0,2] + [ 'and ' + last ]).join(', ')
  end
end
```

There's a number of ways you might do that, but this is a fairly concise approach with a minimum number of branches. You want to avoid repeating yourself, that's how bugs are made, and consolidate common behaviour into common code. The "liked this" part is one such example.

Now you can do this:

```
def likes(names)
  name_list(names) + ' liked this'
end
```

That way if you want to change the phrasing there's one spot to do it, and you can re-use this method in other situations where you're dealing with lists of names or things.

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this.

```
def say_names(name_arr)
  case name_arr.size
  when 0 then "no one likes this"
  when 1 then "%s likes this"           % name_arr
  when 2 then "%s and %s like this"     % name_arr
  when 3 then "%s, %s and %s like this" % name_arr
  else "%s, %s and %d others like this" % (name_arr[0,2] + [name_arr.size-2])
  end
end

say_names []
  #=> "no one likes this" 
say_names ["Peter"]
  #=> "Peter likes this" 
say_names ["Jacob", "Alex"]
  #=> "Jacob and Alex like this" 
say_names ["Max", "John", "Mark"]
  #=> "Max, John and Mark like this" 
say_names ["Alex", "Jacob", "Mark", "Max", "Trixie"]
  #=> "Alex, Jacob and 3 others like this"
```

There might be slightly shorter ways to write the method but I like the way this reads.

Answer (score 0):

Using your original code and adding a simple ternary expression

```
def likes(names)
  arr = names.empty? ? [] : Array.[](names.split(/\W+/))
  if arr.size == 0
    var = "no one likes this"
    return var
  elsif  arr.size == 1
    return  arr[0]+ " likes this "
  elsif  arr.size == 2
    return  arr[0] + "and #{arr[1]} likes this "
  elsif  arr.size == 3
    return "  #{arr[0]}, #{arr[1]} and #{arr[2]} likes this "
  elsif  arr.size >3
    return  "#{arr[0]}, #{arr[1]} and #{arr.size-1} likes this "
  end
end
```

Should do the trick.

A cleaner way would be to remove all the return statements as ruby implicitly returns the last thing evaluated. As such:

```
def likes(names)
      arr = names.empty? ? [] : Array.[](names.split(/\W+/))
      if arr.size == 0
        "no one likes this"
      elsif  arr.size == 1
        arr[0]+ " likes this "
      elsif  arr.size == 2
        arr[0] + "and #{arr[1]} likes this "
      elsif  arr.size == 3
        "#{arr[0]}, #{arr[1]} and #{arr[2]} likes this "
      elsif  arr.size >3
        "#{arr[0]}, #{arr[1]} and #{arr.size-1} likes this "
      end
    end
```

Lastly, you can put this in two lines, however you would be sacrificing readability as such:

```
def likes(names)
  arr = names.empty? ? [] : Array.[](names.split(/\W+/))
  arr.size == 0 ? "no one likes this" : arr.size == 1 ? arr[0]+ " likes this " : arr.size == 2 ? arr[0] + "and #{arr[1]} likes this" : arr.size == 3 ? "#{arr[0]}, #{arr[1]} and #{arr[2]} likes this " : "#{arr[0]}, #{arr[1]} and #{arr.size-1} likes this "
end
```